# Python function which I can not call from kivy

Tags: python, function, kivy

```
### main.py ###
from kivy.app import App

class MainScreen():
    def button_clicked(self):
        print("*")

class KivyApp(App):
    pass
KivyApp().run()


### kivy.kv ###
MainScreen:
<MainScreen@BoxLayout>:
    Button:
        on_press: root.button_clicked()
```

Why I can not call button_clicked() function from kivy?
I know that I can call it if describe like

> class MainScreen(BoxLayout)

in main.py.  But why I can not with above codes?

Comment: What happens when you call the function ? Do you get any error ?

Comment: It will produce " AttributeError: 'MainScreen' object has no attribute 'button_clicked'".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I am not 100% sure about my answer but here is what I think is happening...

The py file runs first and then the kv file, so if in the py file you have `Class MainScreen(BoxLayout):` the MainScreen class is defined and inherits from BoxLayout... Then the rules are defined in the kV file as normal. When you use the `@BoxLayout` in the kV file the class is created again, so this over rides the first definition of `MainScreen`. As the py `MainScreen` has been over ridden by the kV `MainScreen` the attribute `root.button_clicked()` no longer exists....

If you really need use the `@BoxLayout` in the kV file you could add the function to the app class:

```
class LayoutApp(App):

  def button_clicked(self):
    print("*")
```

And then in the kV file:

```
MainScreen:
<MainScreen@BoxLayout>:
    Button:
       on_press: app.button_clicked()
```

Comment: Thank you for your message and advice ( workaroud ).  I tried it and found that work well.

Comment: Great, if the answer is acceptable make sure to mark it as answered!!